# Regex Match expression include end word

Tags: regex

String = "shall not exceed 10 per cent. per annum/that applicable "

```
Regex I'm trying
(?<=shall not exceed)(.*)(?=per annum)

Output Required = 10 per cent. per annum
Output coming = 10 per cent.
```

But with above regex it doesnt include "per annum", how to include "per annum". We are doing this in asp.net

Code in Asp.net we use...

```
            string regularExpressionPattern = regExPattern.ToString();
            string inputText = inputString
            Regex re = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern);
            foreach (Match m in re.Matches(inputText))
            {
                Response.Write(m.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Make the `per annum`  a part of the consuming pattern - `(?<=shall not exceed).*per annum`. Also, consider `(?<=shall not exceed).*?per annum` or even `shall not exceed(.*?per annum)`

Comment: remove the lookahead `(per annum)`

Comment: @RAN_0915 I don't think a capturing group is relevant either : there's very little use capturing a fixed string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - works fine when i try on regexr.com, but when we do this on asp.net regex code... it doesn't work

Comment: Show the code...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - added the asp.net code

Comment: Then it works well, see https://ideone.com/Iy8T6Q.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - can you add this as an answer pls. so that i can accept. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `per annum` a part of the consuming pattern since when it is inside a positive lookahead the text matched is not added to the whole match value.

You may use

```
string inputText = "shall not exceed 10 per cent. per annum/that applicable";
Regex re = new Regex("shall not exceed(.*?per annum)");
foreach (Match m in re.Matches(inputText))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Iy8T6Q)

**Details**

- `shall not exceed` - a literal string
- `(.*?per annum)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `.*?` - 0+ chars other than newline, as few as possible
  - `per annum` - a literal string.

The Group 1 value can be accessed via `m.Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: incase in above you want to include "shall not exceed" in output what needs to be changed?

Comment: @user3657339 That is really a matter of common logic: `Regex re = new Regex("shall not exceed.*?per annum");` and then `Console.WriteLine(m.Value);`. To match across lines, `"(?s)shall not exceed.*?per annum"`